# Change data type of a specific column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort a dataframe with many columns by a specific column, but first I need to change type from `object` to `int`. How to change the data type of this specific column while keeping the original column positions?

Comment: Is posiible use `df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(int)` ?

Comment: did you try to search for this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=pandas%20convert%20to%20int there are lots of related questions. It also depends a lot on the current make up of your data, for instance if you have missing values then you can't convert to int as `NaN` cannot be represented by `int`

Comment: Or you need convert to `int` only for sorting and then convert back to `string` (`object`)?

Comment: @jezrael yes please. I need to convert back after sorting

Comment: @DougKruger - `df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(int)` works or `error` ?

Comment: it works. I'm getting this warning `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` How to suppress this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by sorted  column by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'colname':['7','3','9'],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  D  E  F colname
0  1  4  1  5  7       7
1  2  5  3  3  4       3
2  3  6  5  6  3       9

print (df.colname.astype(int).sort_values())
1    3
0    7
2    9
Name: colname, dtype: int32

print (df.reindex(df.colname.astype(int).sort_values().index))
   A  B  D  E  F colname
1  2  5  3  3  4       3
0  1  4  1  5  7       7
2  3  6  5  6  3       9

print (df.reindex(df.colname.astype(int).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True))
   A  B  D  E  F colname
0  2  5  3  3  4       3
1  1  4  1  5  7       7
2  3  6  5  6  3       9
```

If first solution does not works because `None` or bad data use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'colname':['7','3','None'],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  D  E  F colname
0  1  4  1  5  7       7
1  2  5  3  3  4       3
2  3  6  5  6  3    None

print (pd.to_numeric(df.colname, errors='coerce').sort_values())
1    3.0
0    7.0
2    NaN
Name: colname, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 36):

`df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(int)` works when changing from `float` values to `int` atleast.

Comment: this worked for me. I had this problem and all the answers I found seemed way overly complicated thanks for simple anwser :)

Answer (score 14):

I have tried following:

```
df['column']=df.column.astype('int64')
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

To simply change one column, here is what you can do:
`df.column_name.apply(int)`

you can replace `int` with the desired datatype you want e.g `(np.int64)`, `str`, `category`.

For multiple datatype changes, I would recommend the following:

`df = pd.read_csv(data, dtype={'Col_A': str,'Col_B':int64})`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) provides all the information needed. Let's take the toy dataframe from the docs:

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
```

If we want to cast `col1` to `int32` we can use, for instance, a dictionary:

```py
df.astype({'col1': 'int32'})
```

In addition, the approach above allows to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.