# Values on dataframe dont appear with decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, numpy-slicing

When I'm changing the values of a data frame, the values don't appear with decimals but full numbers.

Why does this happen?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Values'] = range(10,15)

lst = [1.11, 2.22 ,3.33,4.44,5.55]

for x in range(0,5):
  df['Values'][x] = lst[x]

print(test)
```

Comment: You need to change the dtype from `int` to `float`.

Comment: change the dtype of what?

Comment: Of the `Values` column.

Comment: can you please exemplify? I will give you the upvote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590884/change-data-type-of-a-specific-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: When you create the Series you create as an int type, so it assumes anything else you add needs to be an int.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this after `df['Values'] = range(10,15)`:

```
df['Values'] = pd.to_numeric(df["Values"], downcast="float")
```

Comment: i did a simplification example of what I really need. In real live,  the values of the list will come from an Rest API and each call needs to be stored on the dataframe as I showed

Answer (score 0):

This work out for me! Thanks for the help

```
test = pd.DataFrame()

test['Values'] = range(10,15)
test['Values'] = test['Values'].astype(float)

lst = [1.11, 2.22 ,3.33,4.44,5.55]

for x in range(0,5):
  test['Values'][x] = float(lst[x])

test
```